# Discord bot - metadata from icecast stream JSON

Tags: javascript, json, discord, discord.js, icecast

I am looking for some advice to get this feature working on our discord bot. I need to get the metadata from 1 specific icecast stream. The metadata would only include the artist and song playing at that moment.

What features would include:

- Display the metadata in a message when using a command
- Display the metadata as the status of the bot ex: Listening to (metadata)

I have seen some topics on this already but never a real approach to this or very vague. Any documentation or articles that would help with this are welcome. Bot written in JSON

basic setup bot:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.login(process.env.token);

client.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('Curve Bot is online! :)');
    client.user.setActivity("curveradio.com", {type: "LISTENING"});
});
```

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Comment: Hey Tenclea! I have been looking into various npms to get this working. Mostly it really confuses me. Especially since there are few examples and real documentation on this. These 2 seems to have the most potential, but I really struggle to make anything of it into a command. https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-internet-radio + https://www.npmjs.com/package/icecast-parser